# Applescript: click on specific menu bar item

Tags: applescript

Im make an applescript for application called. But i have a problem with exception :(

Sorry, but "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

- https://i.ibb.co/ZMgZ5Tb/Screen-Shot-2019-04-02-at-10-22-29.png
- https://i.ibb.co/6sGyNjx/Screen-Shot-2019-04-02-at-10-22-41.png

Where is my problem?

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "EndpointConnect"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click
        click menu item "Disconnect" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Actual result is:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of process \"EndpointConnect\". Invalid index." number -1719 from menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of process "EndpointConnect"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script as it stands executes a `click` on an object that doesn't (yet) exist.  Basically, you need a `delay` between the two `click` commands to give the system time to instantiate the menu and its items.

Here's an edit that I can't test for you, but I'm hopeful will work:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
    process "EndpointConnect" to tell ¬
    menu bar 2 to tell ¬
    menu bar item 1

    if not (exists) then return null

    click

    tell (a reference to menu item "Disconnect" of menu 1)
        repeat until it exists
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        click
    end tell
end tell
```

However, for some unknown reason, you'll probably get an annoying 5-second delay between the appearance of the menu and the clicking of the menu item.  It's well-known/-documented, often complained about, and a years-long problem that hasn't been fixed, and probably never will be.